# TFS & TDS Integration In TFS Build Server

Tags: tfs, continuous-integration, sitecore, tds

I wanted to explore How TDS can be used with TFS build server to generate update package during build and install the same in CM server using TDS package installer so that I can select the appropriate tools for our deployment process .

What I have read is Tds needs to be installed in Tfs build server But I am not sure what things needs to be configured in Tfs build server so that it will generate the update package during the build .

Once it generates the update package how we can deploy the same to CM server using Tds Package installer . We would be using octopus for deployment . So if I can get help on this for the complete start to end sitecore content deployment using Tds it would really great for me and I can come to a decision .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of [TDS 5.5](http://www.hhogdev.com/blog/2016/february/tds55-release-notes.aspx) you don't need to install on the build server and can use cloud build by installing a nuget package:  http://hedgehogdevelopment.github.io/tds/chapter5.html#tds-builds-using-cloud-servers

There are a number of tools available for installing the package, such as [Sitecore Ship](https://github.com/kevinobee/Sitecore.Ship), [Fortis Update Package Installer](http://fortis.ws/fortis-collection/toolcore/update-package-installation/) or [various tools](http://www.hhogdev.com/blog/2015/september/sitecore-package-deployer.aspx) by Hedgehog themselves (including command line tools bundled with TDS). You'll need to create a deployment step in Octopus to install the package. You can find some info to help in [this blog post](http://goblinrockets.com/2015/11/15/update-2-continuous-integration-deployment-sitecore-publishing/).

Comment: Can you please help me with the steps please ? I would need to add HedgehogDevelopment.TDS.[x.x.x.x].nupkg, to my tds project . If I add this to my tds project do I need to add a the same to Private nuget repo ,Actually we dont ve private nuget repo . Once I add HedgehogDevelopment.TDS.[x.x.x.x].nupkg to my tds project ,What all config changes I need to make in order to generate the update package in server .

Comment: How TDS picks the configuration settings respective to environment ? I need to define different configurations for my dev test act and prd envs . So what parameter I need to configure so that if the build is happening for dev it will pick the dev configuration . Also the update package file would be created under the drop folder ?

Comment: For the nuget package, [host your own feed](https://docs.nuget.org/create/hosting-your-own-nuget-feeds) or check-in the expanded folders from the packages folder, it will then be always available during build.

Comment: TDS uses project configurations and you can set up different configurations for different builds in much the same way as you can for standard .Net which you must add to your VS solution and they will then be available in TDS. Additionally you can also add a [global config](http://hedgehogdevelopment.github.io/tds/chapter4.html#global-config). The update package folder is created in another folder alongside the folder specified in [Build Output Path](http://hedgehogdevelopment.github.io/tds/chapter4.html#build)

Comment: Thanks .. I will try it out .